# ASP.NET MVC - State and Architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After a pair programming session, an interesting question came up which I think I know the answer for.

Question:  Is there any other desired way in ASP.NET MVC to retain 'state' other than writing to database or a text file?

I'm going to define state here to mean that we have a collection of person objects, we create a new one, and go to another page, and expect to see the newly created person.  (so no Ajax)

My thoughts are we don't want any kung-fu ViewState or other mechanisms, this framework is about going back to a stateless web.

Comment: Hi Jfar - agreed this would have been better as a normal question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *My thoughts are we don't want any kung-fu ViewState or other mechanisms, this framework is about going back to a stateless web.*

The example you provided is pretty easy to do without any sort of "view state kung fu" using capabilities that are already in MVC. "User adds a person and sees that on the next screen." Let me code up a simple `PersonController` that does exactly what you want:

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    return View(new Person());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(PersonViewModel myNewPersonViewModel)
{
    //validate, user entered everything correctly
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    //map model to my database/entity/domain object
    var myNewPerson = new Person()
    {
        FirstName = myNewPersonViewModel.FirstName,
        LastName = myNewPersonViewModel.LastName
    }

    // 1. maintains person state, sends the user to the next view in the chain
    // using same action
    if(MyDataLayer.Save(myNewPerson))
    {
        var persons = MyDataLayer.GetPersons();
        persons.Add(myNewPersion);

        return View("PersonGrid", persons); 
    }

    //2. pass along the unique id of person to a different action or controller
    //yes, another database call, but probably not a big deal 
    if(MyDataLayer.Save(myNewPerson))
        return RedirecToAction("PersonGrid", ...etc pass the int as route value);

    return View("PersonSaveError", myNewPersonViewModel);
}
```

Now, what I'm sensing is that you want person on yet another page after `PersonSaveSuccess` or something else.  In that case, you probably want to use `TempData[""]` which is a single serving session and only saves *state* from one request to another or manage the traditional `Session[""]` yourself somehow.

What is confusing to me is you're probably going to the db to get all your persons anyway.  If you save a person it should be in your persons collection in the next call to your `GetPersons()`. If you're not using Ajax, than what state are you trying to persist?

Comment: Thanks jfar - am still playing with your code.. back to it tomorrow :-)  Although what I'm really getting at is covered in my comments above - we're really going towards stateless architecure when possible.

Answer (score 1):

What about user session?  There are plenty of valid use cases to store things in session.  And what about a distributed caching system like memcached?   You also seem to leave out the query string - which is an excellent state saver (?page=2).  To me those seem like other desirable methods to save state across requests...?

Comment: Thanks.. and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490391/how-should-i-integrate-session-state-into-an-asp-net-mvc-application reinforces what you say.  It seems like we're really trying to go back to stateless when possible, and to KISS :-)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC offers a cleaner way of working with session storage using model binding. You can write a custom model binder that can supply instances from session to your action methods. Look it up.

Comment: Many thanks - http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx  this is good.