# Does a controller maintain state while the page is not refreshed?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to put two private variables in my controller. I am going to fill these when the page loads by making an ajax call on the front end to get some user IP data, and fill these variables.

Can I be sure that they will be filled throughout the user experience with the site as long as they don't refresh the page (upon refreshed they will be set again), or does MVC not work this way?

Comment: You don't say what language / framework you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mvc is stateless. Fullstop.

[ASP.NET MVC - State and Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353878/asp-net-mvc-state-and-architecture)

Answer (score 1):

As it is pointed out MVC is stateless.

The only data storage outside server side storage (like custom DB or Asp.Net in session state) that survives GET requests and avaialbe for both server and client is cookies. Note that cookie size is limited (vairying per browser - around 4K per cookie, under 100 cookies/100K total per domain).

Answer (score 0):

Controller is stateless. It doesn't hold the values of initialized private variables.

Comment: How would I do this sort of thing without DB persistence? This user info cannot be saved but I only have access to it on page load.